# Include ftl file in ext plugin

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-6

I have ext-plugin and I would like to override this file: portal-impl\src\com\liferay\portlet\dynamicdatamapping\dependencies\ddm\documentlibrary.ftl. After maven build, this file isn't include in my porta-impl-ext.jar.

In my portal-impl-ext's pom.xml I have this code:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <apiBaseDir>${basedir}/../my-ext-service</apiBaseDir>
                <implBaseDir>${basedir}</implBaseDir>
                <sqlDir>${basedir}/../my-ext/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/sql</sqlDir>
                <webappBaseDir>${basedir}/../my-ext-web</webappBaseDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In my portal-ext's pom.xml I have this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                <pluginName>my-ext</pluginName>
                <pluginType>ext</pluginType>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried to change include section, but it didn't work. It is possible to include this file?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is moving file from source folder to resource folder.